# Flutter ios build fail, android works

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, flutter-dependencies

The app was developed using flutter, ran, and tested on android only until the build is done.

Getting the following log with error while trying to run the app on simulation iPhone.

```
The plugin `video_thumbnail` uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding.
To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to see if this
plugin supports the Android V2 embedding. Otherwise, consider removing it since a
future release of Flutter will remove these deprecated APIs.
If you are plugin author, take a look at the docs for migrating the plugin to the
V2 embedding: https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration.
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running pod install...                                             11.6s
Running Xcode build...                                                  
Xcode build done.                                           22.0s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
 ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
 warning: [CP] Unable to find matching .xcframework slice in
 '/Users/dilbe/Downloads/millions_frontend/ios/Pods/mobile-ffmpeg-https/mobilef
 fmpeg.xcframework mobileffmpeg framework ios-arm64 ios-x86_64-simulator
 ios-x86_64-maccatalyst' for the current build architectures (arm64 x86_64).
 warning: [CP] Unable to find matching .xcframework slice in
 '/Users/dilbe/Downloads/millions_frontend/ios/Pods/mobile-ffmpeg-https/libavco
 dec.xcframework libavcodec framework ios-x86_64-simulator
 ios-x86_64-maccatalyst ios-arm64' for the current build architectures (arm64
 x86_64).
 warning: [CP] Unable to find matching .xcframework slice in
 '/Users/dilbe/Downloads/millions_frontend/ios/Pods/mobile-ffmpeg-https/libavde
 vice.xcframework libavdevice framework ios-arm64 ios-x86_64-maccatalyst
 ios-x86_64-simulator' for the current build architectures (arm64 x86_64).
 warning: [CP] Unable to find matching .xcframework slice in
 '/Users/dilbe/Downloads/millions_frontend/ios/Pods/mobile-ffmpeg-https/libavfi
 lter.xcframework libavfilter framework ios-x86_64-maccatalyst
 ios-x86_64-simulator ios-arm64' for the current build architectures (arm64
 x86_64).
 warning: [CP] Unable to find matching .xcframework slice in
 '/Users/dilbe/Downloads/millions_frontend/ios/Pods/mobile-ffmpeg-https/libavfo
 rmat.xcframework libavformat framework ios-arm64 ios-x86_64-maccatalyst
 ios-x86_64-simulator' for the current build architectures (arm64 x86_64).
 warning: [CP] Unable to find matching .xcframework slice in
 '/Users/dilbe/Downloads/millions_frontend/ios/Pods/mobile-ffmpeg-https/libavut
 il.xcframework libavutil framework ios-x86_64-simulator ios-arm64
 ios-x86_64-maccatalyst' for the current build architectures (arm64 x86_64).
 warning: [CP] Unable to find matching .xcframework slice in
 '/Users/dilbe/Downloads/millions_frontend/ios/Pods/mobile-ffmpeg-https/libswre
 sample.xcframework libswresample framework ios-x86_64-simulator
 ios-x86_64-maccatalyst ios-arm64' for the current build architectures (arm64
 x86_64).
 warning: [CP] Unable to find matching .xcframework slice in
 '/Users/dilbe/Downloads/millions_frontend/ios/Pods/mobile-ffmpeg-https/libswsc
 ale.xcframework libswscale framework ios-arm64 ios-x86_64-simulator
 ios-x86_64-maccatalyst' for the current build architectures (arm64 x86_64).
 warning: [CP] Unable to find matching .xcframework slice in
 '/Users/dilbe/Downloads/millions_frontend/ios/Pods/mobile-ffmpeg-https/gmp.xcf
 ramework gmp framework ios-arm64 ios-x86_64-simulator ios-x86_64-maccatalyst'
 for the current build architectures (arm64 x86_64).
 warning: [CP] Unable to find matching .xcframework slice in
 '/Users/dilbe/Downloads/millions_frontend/ios/Pods/mobile-ffmpeg-https/gnutls.
 xcframework gnutls framework ios-x86_64-simulator ios-x86_64-maccatalyst
 ios-arm64' for the current build architectures (arm64 x86_64).
 warning: [CP] Unable to find matching .xcframework slice in
 '/Users/dilbe/Downloads/millions_frontend/ios/Pods/mobile-ffmpeg-https/libhogw
 eed.xcframework libhogweed framework ios-arm64 ios-x86_64-maccatalyst
 ios-x86_64-simulator' for the current build architectures (arm64 x86_64).
 warning: [CP] Unable to find matching .xcframework slice in
 '/Users/dilbe/Downloads/millions_frontend/ios/Pods/mobile-ffmpeg-https/libnett
 le.xcframework libnettle framework ios-x86_64-simulator ios-arm64
 ios-x86_64-maccatalyst' for the current build architectures (arm64 x86_64).
 In file included from
 /Users/dilbe/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/better_playe
 r-0.0.73/ios/Classes/BetterPlayerPlugin.m:5:
 In file included from
 /Users/dilbe/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/better_playe
 r-0.0.73/ios/Classes/BetterPlayerPlugin.h:12:
 /Users/dilbe/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/better_playe
 r-0.0.73/ios/Classes/BetterPlayer.h:52:34: warning: 'width' used as the name
 of the previous parameter rather than as part of the selector
 [-Wmissing-selector-name]
 - (void)setTrackParameters:(int) width: (int) height: (int)bitrate;
                                  ^
 /Users/dilbe/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/better_playe
 r-0.0.73/ios/Classes/BetterPlayer.h:52:34: note: introduce a parameter name to
 make 'width' part of the selector
 /Users/dilbe/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/better_playe
 r-0.0.73/ios/Classes/BetterPlayer.h:52:39: note: or insert whitespace before
 ':' to use 'width' as parameter name and have an empty entry in the selector
 - (void)setTrackParameters:(int) width: (int) height: (int)bitrate;
                                       ^
 /Users/dilbe/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/better_playe
 r-0.0.73/ios/Classes/BetterPlayer.h:52:47: warning: 'height' used as the name
 of the previous parameter rather than as part of the selector
 [-Wmissing-selector-name]
 - (void)setTrackParameters:(int) width: (int) height: (int)bitrate;
                                               ^
 /Users/dilbe/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/better_playe
 r-0.0.73/ios/Classes/BetterPlayer.h:52:47: note: introduce a parameter name to
 make 'height' part of the selector
 /Users/dilbe/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/better_playe
 r-0.0.73/ios/Classes/BetterPlayer.h:52:53: note: or insert whitespace before
 ':' to use 'height' as parameter name and have an empty entry in the selector
 - (void)setTrackParameters:(int) width: (int) height: (int)bitrate;
                                                     ^
 /Users/dilbe/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/better_playe
 r-0.0.73/ios/Classes/BetterPlayerPlugin.m:179:64: warning: use of C-style
 parameters in Objective-C method declarations is deprecated
 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
 - (void) setupRemoteCommandNotification:(BetterPlayer*)player, NSString*
 title, NSString* author , NSString* imageUrl{
```

etc

```
    ^
    35 warnings generated.
    In file included from
    /Users/dilbe/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_ffmp
    eg-0.4.2/ios/Classes/FlutterFFmpegPlugin.m:20:
    /Users/dilbe/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_ffmp
    eg-0.4.2/ios/Classes/EmptyLogDelegate.h:20:10: fatal error:
    'mobileffmpeg/LogDelegate.h' file not found
    #include <mobileffmpeg/LogDelegate.h>
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Analyzing workspace
    note: Constructing build description
    note: Build preparation complete
```

I cloned the project from Github and tried many debugging including - clearing of cache, pod reinstall, and flutter pub get.
I don't know where I failed but help me out.